# Video iFrames not always displaying on Vercel

Tags: iframe, youtube, svelte, vercel, sveltekit

I have a SvelteKit project, deployed to Vercel with a few videos embedded in one of the pages.

Nothing fancy just:

```
<iframe  class="player-ratio" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/video_link" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

This works locally, it also works when I run `yarn run build && yarn run preview` to view the production version of the site.

However, when actually deployed on most browsers this is what actually renders:

```
<iframe class="player-ratio" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen="" data-src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/video_link" data-categories="performance" data-autoblocked="1">
   #document
   <html>
     <head></head>
     <body></body>
   </html>
</iframe>
```

So the iFrame is rendering but the content coming back from YouTube is an empty HTML page.  I have another video on Vimeo, same issue.
After a few hours the videos do show up for me, but if I check another browser or go incognito the issue persists. I believe this is true for other users.

I'm not sure if this is a Vercel thing, or Svelte or Youtube.  Any pointers in the right direction would be much appreciated.

Comment: Would recommend checking the network tab of the browser dev tools to inspect requests and their responses.

Comment: Headers are identical, but the working one has a response of an HTML document, that does not response is `Failed to load response data: No resource with given identifier found`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm still not 100% sure on the root cause, but from what I can tell this was an issue with my SSR site where the component was rendered before the page load and YouTube didn't like that.

I fixed this by explicitly lazy-loading the iFrames using the `vanilla-lazyload` NPM package.

```
import lazyload from 'vanilla-lazyload';

let lazyLoadInstance;

onMount(() => {
 lazyloadInstance = new lazyload();
}

...

<iframe class="lazy player-ratio" src="" data-src="link" frameborder="0" title="Vimeo player" />
```

Note that `vanilla-lazyload` requires the `src` to be blank, you put the source of the video in `data-src`.